# Parsing ELF sections

Tags: c, elf, sections

Hi so I am trying to code a program which parses an ELF then creates a copy of it using the parsed info.
I’ve been able to copy the elf header and program headers of elf files (readelf -l and -h are identical to orignal). But I’m struggling with sections

```
int parse64elfsec(t_elf_file ef)
{
    Elf64_Shdr shdr;
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)ef.file  + ef.elf64header.e_shoff;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while (i < ef.elf64header.e_shnum)
    {
        memcpy(&shdr, ptr, sizeof(Elf64_Shdr));
        ptr += sizeof(Elf64_Shdr);
        if (shdr.sh_type != SHT_NOBITS)
        {
            write(ef.wfd, (unsigned char *)ef.file + shdr.sh_offset, shdr.sh_size);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0); 
}
```

This is what I’m currently doing but I’m not getting all the sections it seems because the product binary is half the size of the original one and segfaults.

Can anyone see what I’m missing out on here ?

Edit :

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/SaltyMilk/woody-woodpacker/tree/a9b8e0ea601ec21b7bdd19ccd314513504240418) if someone wishes to have the full context/try it.

All macros and structs used here are defined by elf.h (man 5 elf).
Except t_elf_file, this contains

- ef.file -> original executable mapped in memory
- ef.wfd -> file descriptor of the copy executable we're creating
- ef.elf64header -> the Elf64_Ehdr (header) of the executable we're parsing

edit 2:
After some more research I printed the offsets at which each section starts and ends:

```
Finished to parse ph, they finish at : 2a8
Starting to parse section start: 0 | end : 0
Starting to parse section start: 2a8 | end : 2c4
Starting to parse section start: 2c4 | end : 2e4
Starting to parse section start: 2e4 | end : 308
Starting to parse section start: 308 | end : 32c
Starting to parse section start: 330 | end : 3d8
Starting to parse section start: 3d8 | end : 45a
Starting to parse section start: 45a | end : 468
Starting to parse section start: 468 | end : 488
Starting to parse section start: 488 | end : 548
Starting to parse section start: 548 | end : 560
Starting to parse section start: 1000 | end : 1017
Starting to parse section start: 1020 | end : 1040
Starting to parse section start: 1040 | end : 1048
Starting to parse section start: 1050 | end : 11b1
Starting to parse section start: 11b4 | end : 11bd
Starting to parse section start: 2000 | end : 2010
Starting to parse section start: 2010 | end : 204c
Starting to parse section start: 2050 | end : 2158
Starting to parse section start: 2de8 | end : 2df0
Starting to parse section start: 2df0 | end : 2df8
Starting to parse section start: 2df8 | end : 2fd8
Starting to parse section start: 2fd8 | end : 3000
Starting to parse section start: 3000 | end : 3020
Starting to parse section start: 3020 | end : 3030
Starting to parse section start: 3030 | end : 3038
Starting to parse section start: 3030 | end : 304c
Starting to parse section start: 3050 | end : 3650
Starting to parse section start: 3650 | end : 3852
Starting to parse section start: 3852 | end : 3959
First section header at : 3960
```

We can see multiple odd things :

1)

```
Starting to parse section start: 3030 | end : 3038
Starting to parse section start: 3030 | end : 304c
```

->those two sections start at the same offset

2)

```
Starting to parse section start: 308 | end : 32c
Starting to parse section start: 330 | end : 3d8
```

->those two sections don't follow each other, therefore what are those bytes between those two sections ?

To get that output I simply added this printf above the if in the given code

```
printf("Starting to parse section start: %lx | end : %lx\n",  shdr.sh_offset, shdr.sh_offset + shdr.sh_size);
```

Comment: You should provide to us a compilable program. In that way, we can understand what we see. Personally, I do not know what "Elf64_Shdr" is. With a full program, I could understand at least if it is provided by a library, or you wrote it yourself.

Comment: I guess a "for()" would have been nicer instead of "while()".

Comment: Alright thanks for the guidance, I'll update my question with that additional info. Btw Elf64_Shdr is defined by elf.h (man 5 elf).

Comment: You should check if `e_shentsize` in the file matches `sizeof(Elf64_Shdr);` on your machine. If this ELF was compiled for different arch, you might be reading the section headers wrong.

Comment: Yup they're both 64bytes, the binary I'm testing this on was compiled in the exact same environment as my dev env. I appreciate the help though thanks !
Also I'm pretty sure I read the section headers correctly because if I parse header+ parse program headers + fill with all the bytes till the section headers then parse section headers. I get a perfect copy of the executable.

Comment: Without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you are unlikely to get a useful answer. No, pointing to github doesn't substitute for that. Overlapping sections are uncommon, chances are you are not parsing sections correctly. You should be able to compare what you parse with the output from `readelf -WS ...` -- they should match one to one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.